# Super High CPU Usage with only Audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, cpu

Preface:

All below is REGARDLESS of --audio-device=alsa or --audio-device=pulse. The similar thing happens with either mplayer or mpv. Both on Arch and Debian 10.x stable.

Steps to reproduce (Arch):

1. Open Konsole/Terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>),
2. Type the following music audio stream:

   ```
   $ mpv https://secure.live-streams.nl/flac.flac
   ```

   You will get bunch of errors of ffmpeg, but the stream will play regardless:

   These are errors of ffmpeg with FLAC stream that spike CPU usage (gradually) to 100%:

   ```
   (+) Audio --aid=1 (flac 2ch 44100Hz) [ffmpeg/audio] 
   flac: Multiple frames in a packet. 
   AO: [pulse] 44100Hz stereo 2ch s32 [ffmpeg/audio] 
   flac: invalid sync code [ffmpeg/audio] 
   flac: invalid frame header [ffmpeg/audio] 
   flac: decode_frame() failed Error decoding audio. Invalid audio PTS: 0.092880 -> 1552320.005805
   ```
3. Immediately open new Konsole tab
4. Type `$ htop`
5. Press <kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and type `mpv`.
6. Observe how steadily but gradually CPU usage runs into 100%.

Weirdly it doesn't happen with opus or vorbis or mpeg layer 3 at all.

Weirdly `VLC ($ cvlc https://secure.live-streams.nl/flac.flac)` also does fire up multiple instances of itself -just like mpv- but soon kills them and there's one with "small CPU" usage.

Does that mean that VLC has some special "tweaked version" of official ffmpeg and the rest can't kill whatever ffmpeg nutty behavior?

Please Fix it.

PS. mplayer uses more than 2x less CPU than mpv while playing the same audio.
And please do not blame mpv or mplayer, cause there are bunch of errors while playing this music stream (https://secure.live-streams.nl/flac.flac).

Comment: Stack Exchange users cannot fix your issues with third party software. If your stream is not compliant to specifications it may be that one software is able to play it without side effects and the other is not. You should present your findings to the author of the software that creates the CPU load and to the stream provider as well. Your stream provider has an interest that his stream can played on a wide range of software without disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

## Upgrade your ffmpeg

Lazy test shows that the CPU load is reproducible with FFmpeg 4.3.1, but not with a build from the git master branch (compiled with `--enable-gnutls` for HTTPS support). I did not perform a `git bisect` or search the [bug tracker](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/).

Testing command (you will hear nothing):

```
ffmpeg -i https://secure.live-streams.nl/flac.flac -f null -
```

Upgrade `ffmpeg` and re-link/re-compile the dependent players or wait for FFmpeg 4.4.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell it to Debian (my main production system). Arch will follow. Thank you again.